# my font family is not working on css and i can not find it on google fonts

Tags: html, css, font-family

I am trying to recreate this homepage for practice in html and css. https://cgr-consulting.ca/#join. I am not sure how to find the font for the navbar, specifically the  "about us", "our mission" and "contact us" links. I have tried looking in the html head at the font links but it's extremely confusing.... my code is below.

```
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li><a href='about.html'>about</a></li>
            <li><a href="our-mission.html">our mission</a></li>
            <li><a href='contact-us'>contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>



    li a {
      font-family: 'Cirka Light__subset', Cirka Light, Times New 
      Roman, Georgia, serif;

     }
```

I have grabbed this font family, from the linked website using the inspect tool, then going to  the navbar. this is the font what comes up ^^, yet it does nothing.

Comment: Have you tried searching for Cirka font?

Comment: The font they are using is actually a paid one so maybe just go to [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com) and pick one thats similar?

Comment: It does nothing because you have to have the font installed/downloaded.

Comment: @AHaworth yh, says cant find any fonts. i have tried multiple sites, but not found it

Comment: @Laisender ahhh thanks, will look for another one

Comment: Just google (or whatever search engine you use) the two words 'Cirka font'. It leads you to the font's site - apparently you can try it for free then they sell a license.

Answer (score 0):

To use any custom `font-family` you need to use ***`@import`*** property to import the font from some link. In your case you can import it from [here](https://www.onlinewebfonts.com/download/48a569e2727e204524df572f7ad451a5) .

```css
@import url(//db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/48a569e2727e204524df572f7ad451a5?family=Cirka+Light);

    li a {
     font-family: "Cirka Light";
    }
```

```html
<nav>
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li><a href='about.html'>about</a></li>
            <li><a href="our-mission.html">our mission</a></li>
            <li><a href='contact-us'>contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```